# ESC's Brushless Motor PSU and Maximum Torque

Tags: arduino, power-supply, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I am looking to purchase DC 12V 83.3A 1000W Power Supply and will use 4 brushless motors A2212 1400KV Brushless Motor. I have checked the Motors and they require 11.1 V and Load Current: 19.0A Power:210W. The ESC's will be 30a bi directional.

From my understanding the power supply I am looking to purchase would meet the requirements to run the motors at full torque at the same time.

My questions is theoretically will the PSU be sufficient to power the 4 brushless motors at max torque at the same time - although I probably would not want to make them work at 100% probably at 80% but I am just interested to know if I am correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes 1000W will power four 210W loads. There is also more to consider, and that is the efficiency of the power supply. Most SMPS power supplies have an efficiency somewhere in the range of 95 to 80 percent. But the 1000W is at the output of this supply because 12V*83.3A is 1000W, so the efficiency doesn't need to be considered. But the supply could draw more than 1000W on the input.

Another thing to check is the current, four motors will draw 19A*4=76A so the 83.3A will be more than sufficient to run the motors.

Also make sure you have good cabling as amps of current will cause a noticeable voltage drop on the cables if smaller wire gauges are used.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer this was very helpful!